# Split and count the values merged with delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a|b|c|d|.. values in a cell. How can I use to count the total occurrence of b in all the calls by splitting it with the help of delimiter

Comment: How is that related to SQL ?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: @ Alexandre P. Levasseur  In mssql, I have a column characters. first row has, a|b|c|d and second row has b|a|h|o|, third has o|h|a|b, I need the total occurance of every individual characters. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you need to count the number of occurances, you can use this (SQL Server):

```
SELECT LEN(yourColumn) - LEN(REPLACE(yourColumn, 'b', '')) FROM yourTable
```

Comment: +1 Topic starter is not clear about a length of separated words. Are they just single chars or words. So I think you should use not just 'b' but '|b|' + check 'b|' in the start of line and '|b' in the end of line.

Comment: But OP wants the total count of all `b`. Have a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e618c/2/1 (imho 4 would be correct) So you're counting `b|bb` as three b's instead of one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, it's not very clear what excactly OP want's from his question. I Suppose our answers and comments will help him to archiev his result

Answer (score 3):

I'm on SQL-Server 2005 and use this `Split` function:

```
SELECT split.Item, count=Count(*)
FROM dbo.Foo f
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(f.ColName, '|')split
GROUP BY split.Item
Having split.Item='b'
```

Here the table valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e618c/1/0)

Comment: Worked for me. :)